# how to attached file in ionic +cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am making a simple app on iOS. Upon clicking a button I want the  **gallery or file chooser  or file explorer** to open, and for the user to be able to select any `.txt` or `.pdf`, `.jpg` or `.png` file  from gallery.

So I want to know how to open file explore in the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/). Is there any plugin available in Ionic or Cordova that opens the file explore and uploads to to a server? I don't want to use the email composer plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a simple [HTML5 file input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html):

```
<input type="file">
```

this should open the native browser on iOS or Android and allow you to select any kind of file. For uploading, you could try the [`$cordovaFileTransfer`](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) plugin.

If you're targeting iOS8, which appears to have issues with the file input, I'd suggest you check out [FineUploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader), a JS solution.

---

Alternatively, you can use [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/)'s [`$cordovaImagePicker`](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/imagePicker/) and [`$cordovaFileTransfer`](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) plugins. [Install ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/) first with Bower or include the JS files manually and inject `ngCordova` as an Angular dependency. Then, install the plugins with:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Then, you can use the `getPictures()` method and the `upload()` methods to select photos on the device and upload them to your server. However, you won't be able to select and upload other kinds of files formats `.txt` or `.pdf` because `$cordovaImagePicker` only picks images

Comment: ok .@huey i got your point ..If I want to select image than I need to go with $cordovaImagePicker ..or if I need to get other file I need to go other option HTMl5  may i correct or is there any other method

Comment: yup! The HTML5 method is actually really straightforward. There's actually the [Cordova FileChooser](https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser) plugin as well, but I haven't personally used it.

Comment: But I saw it is only for android  ? can I used in iOS ? or iPhone ?

Comment: The HTML5 input works for iOS, but the FileChooser's only for Android, yeah.

Comment: thanks HTML5 I think work for both iOS and android ? may i correct ?

Comment: But  I saw some  OS like 8.3 in iPad links in which HTML5 type="file" application crash I will give you that links

Comment: Using above method how am I suppose to provide filepath to  $cordovaFileTransfer.upload?

Answer (score 0):

For catch the image from the gallery device you could this plugin:
 [$ImagePicker](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/imagePicker/).

After googling a bit, i have found this plugin [cordova-plugin-file-opener2](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2),  i think this one could help you to get a file stored on the device.

For the download and upload i have already used this one: [$cordovaFileTransfer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/)

Comment: I don't want to only image .I want to select any file from galllary

Comment: is there any plugin in which user can select any format file and try to send to server

Comment: PDF files in iOS aren't stored in the gallery, they are in iBooks.

Comment: how to attached file other than pdf like text file image file ?